# JQuery find em árvore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho o seguinte contexto:

```
<div class='pai' id='item'>

    <div class='form'>

       <div class='filho' id='item1'>

            <div class='filho' id='item3'>

            </div>

       </div>

       <div class='filho' id='item2'>

       </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Eu gostaria de obter os elementos `.filho` de **primeiro nível** em relação ao elemento `.pai`. Logo eu teria apenas 2 resultados (`item1` e `item2`) desconsiderando `item3`.

> Devo fazer isso sem levar em consideração o `id`, pois usei ele nesse
>   exemplo apenas para deixar mais clara a pergunta. Se possível, também desconsiderar o `form`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podemos considerar o form?

Se sim o seletor seria assim

```
$('.pai > .form > .filho')
```

O seletor **>** considera apenas os filhos diretos do pai desconsiderando a hierarquia.

Exemplo funcional em http://jsfiddle.net/776jy0hs/

Mais sobre isso em https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

**Editado**

Para desconsiderar totalmente qualquer tipo de hierarquia e pegar os primeiros filhos, pode fazer assim:

```
$('.pai .filho:first-of-type');
```

Isso vai selecionar todos os filhos do pai, mais apenas os primeiros do seu tipo

JSFinddler atualizado http://jsfiddle.net/776jy0hs/1/

Mais sobre em https://api.jquery.com/first-of-type-selector/

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @erick-gallani , mas não gostaria de considerar o `form`, vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues existe uma hierarquia pré definida? Ou é mutável? Tipo sempre vai ser a classe .pai e dpeois um elemento e depois os elementos filhos?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues veja a atualização na minha resposta

Answer (score 3):

O elemento de combinação child (P > F) seleciona apenas filhos de primeiro nível.

Como você tem uma div class form no primeiro nível, você poderia pegar os filhos da seguinte forma:

```
$("div.pai > div > .filho")
```

Desse modo, é retornado um array contendo os filhos de id "item1" e "item2", sendo ignorado o "item3", que no caso é filho de item1.

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser assim também.

`$('div.pai').find('.filho').siblings('.filho');`

Busca na árvore os `.filho(s)` e pega apenas os de primeiro grau.

Comment: Mas como eu disse na pergunta, eu preciso de **todos** os filhos do primeiro nível em relação ao pai.

Comment: Editei Jedaías.

Answer (score 0):

você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
$(".pai").children().children(".filho");
```